# When scraping from a from a website with jQuery does the website need to have a reference to jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am writing a script that scrapes ad listings off a website called Gumtree(Australian Craigslist) using `Nightmare.js` and `jQuery` and I am getting an error:

> (node:15902) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: $ is not defined

I was wondering if the website needs a reference like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

for me to scrape it with jQuery.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to provide anymore information/my code

Comment: Mate, this might be helpful. check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: @BikashPrajapati That isn't gonna help unfortunately, I just need to know if a website(that I don't own/have a way to edit the html e.g. ebay)
needs to have that `jQuery` reference

Comment: What happens when you try? Add jQuery to your own website and try to scrape it, then you can answer your own question.

Comment: No. You are using nightmare to make a request and get the document jquery is just being used as a dom selector tool. I recommend against jquery in this case it's 30 something kb you really don't need you can use document.querySelector and querySelectorAll with no issues in a nodejs environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Nightmare.js`, but wrote a few scraper and just run in the Chrome's console. If the website doesn't have jQuery, you can add it with the following script:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jq.onload = jq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') {
        console.log("jQuery loaded");
        jQuery.noConflict();
    };
};
```